# Is applying styles to <form> element a good practice?

Tags: html, css

Applying styles to `<form>` tag is:

a) a good practice, it decreases the count of elements on a page and makes code clear

b) a bad practice because of semantics, use other elements instead, `div` is for style, `form` is for forms

c) don't ask silly questions and focus on real job!

Comment: d) not constructive. This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: The question could sound 'Is there anything wrong with semantics when I use form tag for styling (apply styles to form tag)?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**d) none of the above**

Style the form if that makes life easier for you. It is not against semantics if you do it.

---

**a** - Decreasing the amount of elements is not necessarily a good practice. If creating more elements will make your layout more readable/understandable then go ahead.

**b** - Divs are not for styling, they are there to divide sections in the document

**c** - You should worry about semantics. This is not a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

a) Yes.

b) No. Div is a generic element. It is not for "style" it is for "when nothing else describes the semantics".

Answer (score 1):

A and C. Simple way checking for good answer is: Write a code and validate it with validator.

Answer (score 1):

Since semantics are seperate from style, applying style to a form has no semantic consequences.  Go right ahead and style a form if you like, it makes no difference to the semantic meaning of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, (a) is especially true because:

- You will be reducing the overall filesize of your page, with no real disadvantage (especially if you have multiple forms and run into this a lot).
- You will be reducing the amount of confusion when you have to go back to edit this style in the future (where someone may have the same question as you).
- You will be reducing the ambiguity as to where certain styles come from (e.g. this form has too large of a top margin.  Is that coming from the margin on the `<div>` or the margin on the `<form>`?)
- You will be reducing the possibility of introducing bugs or cross-browser quirks, stemming from browsers not implementing the same default styles on all elements (in this case, the `<form>` element).

While I suppose one could argue that (b) is a "problem" in theory (and should therefore be avoided), it will never be a "problem" in practice.  But as you can see above, wrapping it in a `<div>` can *certainly* be a problem in practice.